# Magento 2.3.7-p4 wrong open external hyperlink

Tags: magento, hyperlink, field-description

After upgrading Magento 2 from 2.3.0 to 2.3.7-p4, the external links in the description field are no longer displayed. Both images and videos.

For example https://soulridershop.com/index.php/duotone-kitesurf-online-o-torino/twintips/44230-3435-9010583133256-duotone-twintips-voyage-2023-138-

Does anyone know how to fix the problem?

I searched the internet for a solution but without success.